# JavaScript regex string check letters after numbers error

Tags: javascript

I got a problem with regex string tests, where I'd like to permit only `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]`, possibly with '-' and '_' if i get past the "letters and numbers only".

```
if ( /\w/g.test(str) ) {}
```

Special character detection is not reacting.

Usual tests I found to detect spaces won't detect spaces and some special characters at the end of string, only when some more characters are typed.
Possibly waiting for combinations which would make it pass?

`[^a-z][^A-Z][^0-9]` doesn't work properly ofc.

`space`, `*`, `$`, `/`, `\` and possibly some more characters are a problem here and when I tried to add multiple checks for these (like `/\s/.test(str)`), special characters didn't pass, but strings which were containing only letters and numbers got blocked.

seems like the problem here are letters after numbers.
example:

```
aaaaa445333 = ok
aaaaa445333s = not ok
```

Any solutions or explanations whats going on?

Comment: one solution i got in mind is splitting string to single characters and then performing checks on them, but i am not sure if that would help, as string containing only spaces == empty string on check...

Comment: btw its nice to farm your rating on edits , best if you can do so multiple times in row to get at least 10 right? but please, try to do so by taking the time to ansver instead :p

Comment: `/^[-a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/`

Comment: btw William-H-M, you missed few slashes to edit (add) there anyway. So hasty to grind...

Comment: thanks jcaron, this seems to work now. i will do some tests and you should think about making it an ansver.